# Deploying a Simple .NET 4.5 Web API Template to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new to AWS ElasticBeanstalk and AWS in general. I want to deploy the default template .NET 4.5 Web API project (no authentication) to Elastic Beanstalk using the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio. Luckily I found [this guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/deployment-beanstalk-traditional.html) that shows exactly how to do what I want in well documented steps.

I am using the default VPC and unchecked the option to create a single EC2 instance.

However, every time I publish the .NET 4.5 Web API default template project to AWS Elastic Beanstalk when following this guide I receive one of the following errors:

1. The following instances have not responded in the allowed command timeout time (they might still finish eventually on their own): [ec2 instance name here]
2. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: AWSEBInstanceLaunchWaitCondition.

On a few occasions the deploy succeeded and I successfully hit the API endpoints (e.g. GET /api/values) from a few devices. The app then became unresponsive and every request sent to the API after this point timed out.

I would like to learn how to use AWS Elastic Beanstalk with the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio to simply deploy and hit some public test API endpoints without the deploy failing or the API becoming unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

I terminated the Elastic Beanstalk instance and all associated services and moved regions (started from scratch on N. California instead of Oregon). I went through the steps on the guide again in the new region and my template Web API app published with no problems.

I suspect that the VPC configuration was incorrect in the original publishing effort, but I am not sure. Changing regions and starting from scratch fixed the problem.